# Ошибка при серелизации json из файла

Tags: python, json, csv

я пытаюсь серелизовать данные из csv файла с помощью json модуля, но вылезает ошибка `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 385 (char 384)` Может кто пожалуйста подсказать, в чем проблема. Код и файл csv приложен [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pcg0fwpzpbthjm2/AABdXUXQJ6_mJeEZk4MJf_mAa?dl=0)

Comment: Код и пример из файла добавьте в сам вопрос. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, не терять свой смысл, если ссылка вдруг станет недоступной (например, если вы захотите почистить свой dropbox диск).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ошибки JSON ужасно неинформативны. предлагаю это исправить

```
from json import decoder


class JSONDecodeErrorEx(decoder.JSONDecodeError):
    region_size = 20

    def __init__(self, msg, doc, pos):
        # super().__init__(msg, doc, pos)

        lineno = doc.count('\n', 0, pos) + 1
        colno = pos - doc.rfind('\n', 0, pos)

        # doc = doc[:pos - 4] + "^" + doc[pos-4:pos-1] + "^" + doc[pos-1:]

        start_pos = pos - self.region_size if pos - self.region_size > 0 else 0
        end_pos = pos + self.region_size if pos + self.region_size < len(doc) else len(doc)
        wrong_doc_region = doc[start_pos:end_pos]
        if start_pos > 0:
            wrong_doc_region = "... " + wrong_doc_region
        if end_pos < len(doc):
            wrong_doc_region += " ..."

        errmsg = '%s: line %d column %d (char %d). Doc: %r' % (msg, lineno, colno, pos, wrong_doc_region)
        ValueError.__init__(self, errmsg)
        self.msg = msg
        self.doc = doc
        self.pos = pos
        self.lineno = lineno
        self.colno = colno


def apply_patch():
    decoder.JSONDecodeError = JSONDecodeErrorEx


apply_patch()
import json
s = """{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}"""
json.loads(s)
```

И трейсбек получится таким.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../jsonex.py", line 46, in <module>
    json.loads(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
__main__.JSONDecodeErrorEx: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 18 column 17 (char 550). Doc: '... p",\n                }\n            }\n     ...'
```

И сразу видно что идет запятая, а потом закрывающая фигурная скобка